What is the fall of Europe in Gabriela Mistral's poem Caída de Europa?
Gabriela Mistral's poem Caída de Europa was published in the 1954 collection Lagar (Winepress). (The poem is dedicated to Roger Caillois, who published a bilingual edition of a selection of Mistral's poems in 1946, but I don't know whether that is even relevant.)
Europe is not mentioned in the poem, except for references to parts of Europe: Sicily, Flanders, Normandy, Campagna, which are all said to be ablaze ("… arden sus miembros llamados Sicilia, /
Flandes, la Normandía y la Campania"). There is also a curious reference to the "American Gaia" (curious because Gaia is a Greek deity).
Is the fall in the title a reference to Europe's fall to Fascism in the 1930s and early 1940s? Can the poem be dated in a way that makes this plausible? (Mistral lived mostly in France and Italy from the 1920s to 1935, so she would have been aware of political developments in Europe at the time.)

Why the downvote on this question?
